# MySQL: Porque no puedo poner mas foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, tablas, mysqldb

estoy realizando una base de datos sobre una serie, pero en varias de las tablas, me da error y no me permite crear mas foreign keys, e intentando variar las tablas, darles distintos nombres a las claves, con CONSTRAINT y sin ello, y tambien he intentado colgar las tablas unas de otras pero no hay manera. ¿Se os ocurre que puede haber mal con mi codigo?
Gracias de antemano

````
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS voltron;
use voltron;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actores (cod_actor INT PRIMARY KEY, nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, fecha DATE NOT NULL, nacionalidad VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT "Spain");

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personajes (cod_per INT PRIMARY KEY, nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, raza VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, grado VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
codigoactor INT, FOREIGN KEY (codigoactor) REFERENCES actores (cod_actor), codigosuperior INT, FOREIGN KEY (codigosuperior) REFERENCES personajes (cod_per));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS planetas (cod_plan INT PRIMARY KEY, galaxia VARCHAR(50), nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capitulos (titulo VARCHAR NOT NULL, fecha DATE NOT NULL, temporada INT, orden INT, PRIMARY KEY(temporada, orden));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS peliculas (cod_pel INT PRIMARY KEY, titulo CHAR NOT NULL, director CHAR NOT NULL, fecha DATE);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personajescapitulos (codigopersonaje INT PRIMARY KEY, Temporada INT, Orden INT, FOREIGN KEY (Temporada) 
REFERENCES capitulos (temporada), FOREIGN KEY (Orden) REFERENCES capitulos (orden));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personajespeliculas (cod_personaje INT, cod_pelicula INT, FOREIGN KEY (cod_personaje) REFERENCES personajes (cod_per), FOREIGN KEY 
(cod_pelicula) REFERENCES peliculas (cod_pel));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS naves (cod_nave INT PRIMARY KEY, ntripulantes INT, nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitas (codigonave INT, codigoplaneta INT, tempo INT, ordencap INT, FOREIGN KEY (codigonave) REFERENCES naves (cod_nave), 
FOREIGN KEY (codigoplaneta) REFERENCES planetas (cod_plan), FOREIGN KEY (tempo) REFERENCES personajescapitulos (Temporada), FOREIGN KEY (ordencap) REFERENCES
personajescapitulos (Orden));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lanzaderas (codigoNave INT, numero INT, personas INT, FOREIGN KEY (codigoNave) REFERENCES visitas (codigonave), 
PRIMARY KEY (codigoNave,numero));```
````

He cambiado varias cosas, pero sigue dando el mismo error en la sexta tabla y en las dos ultimas, he introducido tambien la restriccion de ON DELETE CASDCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, y el motor de tablas InnoDB:´´´

````
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS voltron CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci;

use voltron;
/*Cambiamos la tabla de uso*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actores (
cod_actor INT PRIMARY KEY, 
nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
fecha DATE NOT NULL, 
nacionalidad VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT "Spain")ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla actores, codigo entero clave primaria, nombre obligatorio max 50 car., fecha obligatoria, nacionalidad max 20 car. default Spain*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personajes (
cod_per INT PRIMARY KEY, 
nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
raza VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
grado VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
codigoactor INT, CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGOACTOR FOREIGN KEY (codigoactor) REFERENCES actores (cod_actor), 
codigosuperior INT, CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGOSUPERIOR FOREIGN KEY (codigosuperior) REFERENCES personajes (cod_per))ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla personajes, codigo_personaje entero clave primaria, nombre max 50 car obligatorio, raza max 20 car obligatorio, 
grado max 20 car obligatorio, codigoactor clave foranea (actores), codigosuperior clave foranea (personajes)*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS planetas (
cod_plan INT PRIMARY KEY, 
galaxia VARCHAR(50), 
nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla planetas, codigo_planeta, galaxia, nombre*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capitulos (
titulo CHAR NOT NULL, 
fecha DATE NOT NULL, 
temporada INT, 
orden INT)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla capitulos, titulo, fecha, temporada, orden*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS peliculas (
cod_pel INT PRIMARY KEY, 
titulo CHAR NOT NULL, 
director CHAR NOT NULL, 
fecha DATE)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla peliculas, codigo_pelicula, titulo, director, fecha*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personajescapitulos (
codigopersonaje INT, 
Temporada INT, CONSTRAINT FK_TEMPORADA FOREIGN KEY (Temporada) REFERENCES capitulos (temporada) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
Orden INT, CONSTRAINT FK_ORDEN FOREIGN KEY (Orden) REFERENCES capitulos (orden)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (codigopersonaje, Temporada, Orden))
ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla personajescapitulos, codigo_personaje, temporada, orden, ERROR 1215*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personajespeliculas (
cod_personaje INT, CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGOPERSONAJE FOREIGN KEY (cod_personaje) REFERENCES personajes (cod_per)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
cod_pelicula INT,  CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGOPELICULA FOREIGN KEY(cod_pelicula) REFERENCES peliculas (cod_pel)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla personajespeliculas, codigo_personaje, codigo_pelicula*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS naves (
cod_nave INT PRIMARY KEY, 
ntripulantes INT, 
nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla naves, codigo_nave, ntripulantes, nombre*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitas (
codigonave INT, FOREIGN KEY (codigonave) REFERENCES naves (cod_nave)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
codigoplaneta INT, CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGOPLANETA FOREIGN KEY (codigoplaneta) REFERENCES planetas (cod_plan)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
tempo INT, CONSTRAINT FK_TEMPORADA FOREIGN KEY (tempo) REFERENCES personajescapitulos (Temporada)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ordencap INT, CONSTRAINT FK_ORDEN FOREIGN KEY (ordencap) REFERENCES personajescapitulos (Orden)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE=InnoDB; 
/*Tabla visitas, codigo_nave, codigo_planeta, temporada, orden, ERROR 1215*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lanzaderas (
codigoNave INT, CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGONAVE FOREIGN KEY (codigoNave) REFERENCES visitas (codigonave)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
numero INT, 
personas INT,  
PRIMARY KEY (codigoNave,numero))ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla lanzaderas, codigo_nave, numero, personas, ERROR 1215*/```
````

Comment: Cuál es el error que me muestra?

Comment: Aparece el error, ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: He cambiado unas cuantas cosas pero me sigue dando error en la sexta tabla y en las dos ultimas, como siempre, el ERROR 1215.

Comment: Quizá este enlace pueda ayudarte. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930084/mysql-error-1215-hy000-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint

Answer (score 1):

Las Foreign keys deben referenciar siempre a una primary key de otra tabla. Si esta Primar key es compuesta (formada por múltiples columnas), entonces la Foreign key deberá heredar cada una de estas columnas **en la misma foreign key**.

En esta tabla no tienes definida ninguna Primary:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capitulos (
titulo CHAR NOT NULL, 
fecha DATE NOT NULL, 
temporada INT, 
orden INT)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla capitulos, titulo, fecha, temporada, orden*/
```

Por lo tanto, si intentas definir una foreign key en otra tabla apuntando a ésta, nunca funcionará.

Ese era el caso de la tabla `personajescapitulos`, que referenciaba a `capitulos` sin que ésta tuviera una primary:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personajescapitulos (
codigopersonaje INT, 
Temporada INT, 
CONSTRAINT FK_TEMPORADA FOREIGN KEY (Temporada) REFERENCES capitulos (temporada) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
Orden INT, 
CONSTRAINT FK_ORDEN FOREIGN KEY (Orden) REFERENCES capitulos (orden)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (codigopersonaje, Temporada, Orden))
ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla personajescapitulos, codigo_personaje, temporada, orden, ERROR 1215*/
```

Si ahora añadimos una primary a capitulos...:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capitulos (
titulo CHAR NOT NULL, 
fecha DATE NOT NULL, 
temporada INT, 
orden INT,
PRIMARY KEY(temporada, orden)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla capitulos, titulo, fecha, temporada, orden*/
```

La de `personajescapitulos` quedaría así:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personajescapitulos (
codigopersonaje INT PRIMARY KEY, 
Temporada INT,  
Orden INT, 
CONSTRAINT FK_CAPITULO FOREIGN KEY (Temporada, Orden) REFERENCES capitulos (temporada, orden) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla personajescapitulos, codigo_personaje, temporada, orden*/
```

Así pues, es cuestión de revisar que cada tabla 'padre' tenga definida una primary key, y que cada tabla 'hija' herede todas las columnas que forman la primary key del padre **en la misma contraint fk**

**Aclaración adicional:**

Que una foreign tenga que apuntar a todas las columnas de la primary del padre, no significa que no podamos tener varias relaciones desde una tabla hija a otra padre. Pero para cada una de ellas deberemos heredar todas las columnas de la PK del padre.

Por lo tanto, si tenemos una tabla padre *A* con una primary (PK_col1, PK_col2), y queremos definir dos FKS en una tabla hija *B* apuntando a la *A*, tendremos que la tabla hija tendrá 2 foreign keys con 2 columnas cada una.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando la tabla a la que haces referencia tiene mas de un campo como primary key la foreign key la declaras de esta manera:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capitulos (
  titulo VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
  fecha DATE NOT NULL, 
  temporada INT, 
  orden INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY(temporada, orden)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personajescapitulos (
  codigopersonaje INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  Temporada INT, 
  Orden INT, 
  FOREIGN KEY (Temporada, Orden) REFERENCES capitulos (temporada, Orden)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchisimas gracias!!! Por fin se me han generado todas las tablas, el error era que habia puesto demasiadas CONSTRAINT, y la respuesta anterior me lo ha arreglado. Por si acaso, dejo aqui el codigo resultante:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS voltron CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci;

use voltron;
/*Cambiamos la tabla de uso*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actores (
cod_actor INT PRIMARY KEY, 
nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
fecha DATE NOT NULL, 
nacionalidad VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT "Spain")ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla actores, codigo entero clave primaria, nombre obligatorio max 50 car., fecha obligatoria, nacionalidad max 20 car. default Spain*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personajes (
cod_per INT PRIMARY KEY, 
nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
raza VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
grado VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
codigoactor INT,  
codigosuperior INT, 
CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGOACTOR FOREIGN KEY (codigoactor) REFERENCES actores (cod_actor),
CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGOSUPERIOR FOREIGN KEY (codigosuperior) REFERENCES personajes (cod_per)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla personajes, codigo_personaje entero clave primaria, nombre max 50 car obligatorio, raza max 20 car obligatorio, 
grado max 20 car obligatorio, codigoactor clave foranea (actores), codigosuperior clave foranea (personajes)*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS planetas (
cod_plan INT PRIMARY KEY, 
galaxia VARCHAR(50), 
nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla planetas, codigo_planeta, galaxia, nombre*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capitulos (
titulo CHAR NOT NULL, 
fecha DATE NOT NULL, 
temporada INT, 
orden INT,
PRIMARY KEY(temporada, orden)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla capitulos, titulo, fecha, temporada, orden*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS peliculas (
cod_pel INT PRIMARY KEY, 
titulo CHAR NOT NULL, 
director CHAR NOT NULL, 
fecha DATE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla peliculas, codigo_pelicula, titulo, director, fecha*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personajescapitulos (
codigopersonaje INT PRIMARY KEY, 
Temporada INT,  
Orden INT, 
CONSTRAINT FK_TEMPORADA FOREIGN KEY (Temporada, Orden) REFERENCES capitulos (temporada, orden) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
/*CONSTRAINT FK_ORDEN FOREIGN KEY (Orden) REFERENCES capitulos (orden)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,*/
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla personajescapitulos, codigo_personaje, temporada, orden*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personajespeliculas (
cod_personaje INT, 
cod_pelicula INT,  
CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGOPERSONAJE FOREIGN KEY (cod_personaje) REFERENCES personajes (cod_per)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGOPELICULA FOREIGN KEY(cod_pelicula) REFERENCES peliculas (cod_pel)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla personajespeliculas, codigo_personaje, codigo_pelicula*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS naves (
cod_nave INT PRIMARY KEY, 
ntripulantes INT, 
nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla naves, codigo_nave, ntripulantes, nombre*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitas (
codigonave INT, 
codigoplaneta INT, 
tempo INT, 
ordencap INT, 
CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGONAVE FOREIGN KEY (codigonave) REFERENCES naves (cod_nave)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGOPLANETA FOREIGN KEY (codigoplaneta) REFERENCES planetas (cod_plan)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK_TEMPORADA_ORDEN FOREIGN KEY (tempo, ordencap) REFERENCES personajescapitulos (Temporada, Orden)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
/*CONSTRAINT FK_ORDEN FOREIGN KEY (ordencap) REFERENCES personajescapitulos (Orden)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,*/
)ENGINE=InnoDB; 
/*Tabla visitas, codigo_nave, codigo_planeta, temporada, orden*/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lanzaderas (
codigoNave INT, 
numero INT, 
personas INT, 
CONSTRAINT FK_CODIGO_NAVE FOREIGN KEY (codigoNave) REFERENCES visitas (codigonave)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
PRIMARY KEY (codigoNave,numero)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*Tabla lanzaderas, codigo_nave, numero, personas*/
```